# Finding the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\log(x^2 y^2)}{\log(x+y)}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\Omega := \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x+y>0, x,y \neq 0 \right\}$ and let function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(x,y) := \frac{\log\left(x^2 y^2\right)}{\log(x+y)}$$ Find the limit for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

---

I need some help finding this limit. I tried to substitute $y=mx$, and the candidate is 4 (probably wrong.). As I understand it, I should create a chain of inequalities, arriving at something like

$$ \left| f(x,y) - l \right| \leq \left|h(x,y)\right| $$

where $h(x,y)$ is a function that goes to zero. However, I have no clue how to do this here.

EDIT: obviously, the $l$ above is the candidate limit.

Comment: I would consider the paths $\gamma_1(t)=(t,t^2-t):t\in (0,1)$ $$\gamma_2(t)=(t,t):t>0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, by restricting the function along the line $y=mx$ with $m>0$ we find
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x,mx)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(m^2x^4)}{\log((1+m)x)}
=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{4\log(x)+\log(m^2)}{\log(x)+\log(1+m)}=4.$$
Now consider the non-linear curve such that $x+y=x^a$ with $a>1$ (see also Matthew H.'s hint). By restricting the function along this curve we have that the asymptotic behaviour of the numerator is the same as before, whereas the denominator changes by a constant factor:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x,x^a-x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(x^2 (x^a-x)^2)}{\log(x^a)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(x^4(1-x^{a-1})^2)}{a\log(x)}\\=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{4\log(x)+2\log(1-x^{a-1})}{a\log(x)}=\frac{4}{a}$$
which is different from $4$. Hence we may conclude that the limit does not exist.